# How would I detect if my player is touching a game object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Okay so basically im working on this test project that relies heavily on movement and momentum to complete levels, with a bit of parkour. I need a collider for two reasons, 1. The player touches an object at the end and gets put back into the menu. 2. If the player falls out of the map they die.

I tried a bit messing around with Colliders and at the Docs and while usually id figure it out ive been stumped for 20 minutes looking at Unity's docs and a few questions from here.

```
public GameObject objectCollider;
public GameObject anotherCollider;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (CollisionDetection.IsTouching(objectCollider.gameObject, anotherCollider.gameObject))
    {
        Destroy(plr);
    }
}
```

This is what I got so far.  I get an error from here and if I switch it to if collider object == the other it errors out.

Basically what I want (If you perfer to just post the answer code but comments on it would still be helpful so i learn!) is for one gameobject (player (but in code its objectCollider)) to be detected if it touches the other (a cube (in code its anotherCollider)) and to execute code (for example Destroy(playerObject))

Thank you for any help you bring here, links, code anything!

Comment: `CollisionDetection.IsTouching` doesn't exist in Unity, post your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for:

```
public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.name == "endObject")
        {
            //put back into the menu
        }
    }
```

Once your player enters a collision, it checks the name of whatever object it collided with. Then you can execute what code you want in the if statement.
You can use `collision.collider` for many other things, such as `collision.collider.tag`, but this should give you a start.